# YouTube video embedding is now enabled

Tags: discussion

It is now possible to embed YouTube content in posts here.

#### Embedding Video

1. Upload the content you want to embed to YouTube.
2. When composing your post, paste the URL to the uploaded video in the body, on a line by itself, like so:

   > Where can I get a rain friendly bicycle like this?
   >
   > http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5V2FgwN_re4
3. After you save the post, it will be rendered with an embedded player:

[image: YouTube-embedded video]

You can see some examples of this in action at our AVP site.

- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/1836/record-a-video-without-static-noise
- [How important is it to have an eq pedal in your chain?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2720/how-important-is-it-to-have-an-eq-pedal-in-your-chain)

Comment: [So we've discovered.](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/5319/1259) http://youtu.be/r9EiX1RZDik

Comment: Thank you. I noticed [fairly quickly](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9433/annoying-clicking-sound-from-the-bottom-bracket).